# Plant recommendation for travelling student

Tags: plant-recommendations, plant-care

I am a university student who rents an apartment to live in. Because I study abroad, there are times that I return back at my parent's home. The time I spend there varies from a week up to two months in the summer.

So the question I want to ask is this: given the above time I spend away from my apartment, what would be a good plant to buy? I obviously need one that has the ability to remain alive for up to two months without me taking care of it, if possible. The reason is that I have no auto-watering system since I live in an apartment.

If there are any ways I should take care of my plant before going away, please make sure to note them as they would help out a lot. I have a balcony where I will keep the plant most of the time, but for the two summer months, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Keeping a plant outdoor in the summer for  2 months? I am afraid even a Cactus won't survive a hot and dry summer in a pot for 2 months.

Comment: @b.nota I edited my question, perhaps the phrasing was bad. If it is bad, I am surely not going to keep the plant outdoors in the summer! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so you need plants that can take a few weeks without watering. There are some plants very tough, and can survive weeks without watering (don't put them in the full sun during the long periods of leave).

Here are some suitable plants:

*[Yucca elephantipes](https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/yucca)*

*[Sansevieria](https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/sansevieria)*

*[Dracaena marginata](https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/dracaena-marginata)*

These plant can be left without watering for weeks.

And of course *Cacti*.